# PHP/laravel Adding item to session not saved

Tags: php, laravel

yesterday i started my first laravel project. but i'm having a problem i can't understand.

I'm trying to create a shopping cart, which i keep track of using laravel's session object with my own wrapper. the code looks like this:

```
class SessionController extends Controller
{
 static function getSessionData($key = null, $data = null)
    {
        if($data === null)
        {
            return Session::get($key);
        }

        else
        {
            return Session::get($key, $data);
        }
    }

    static function allSessionData()
    {
        return Session::all();
    }

    static function putSessionData($key = null, $data)
    {
        if ($key === null)
        {
            Session::put($data);
        }
        else
        {
            Session::put($key, $data);
        }
    }

    static function has($key)
    {
        return Session::has($key);
    }
```

Now inside my `ShoppingCart` class i created an `$instance` field, which keeps the shoppingcart data, or creates an empty shopping cart if it's not in the session yet. the code looks like this:

```
class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $session;
    private $sessionName = 'shoppingcart';
    private $instance;
    public $cartItems;

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'shoppingcart';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';   


    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->cartItems = [];
    }

    private function getOrCreateSession()
    {
        if(SessionController::has($this->sessionName))
        {
            $this->instance = SessionController::getSessionData($this->sessionName);
        }

        else
        {
            SessionController::putSessionData($this->sessionName, $this);
            $this->instance = SessionController::getSessionData($this->sessionName);
        }
    }

    function addCartItem($productId, $qty = 1)
    {
        $this->getOrCreateSession();
        $cartItem = $this->createCartitem($productId, $qty);
        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($existingCartitem = $this->alreadyInCart($cartItem)) {
            $existingCartitem->qty += $cartItem->qty;
        } else {
            array_push($content, $cartItem);
        }
    }

    function createCartItem($productId, $qty)
    {
        $cartItem = CartItem::fromId($this->instance->id, $productId, $qty);
        $cartItem->associate($this->instance->id);

        return $cartItem;
    }

    private function alreadyInCart($cartItem)
    {
        $alreadyInCart = FALSE;

        foreach ($this->instance->cartItems as $item) {
            if ($item->productId == $cartItem->productId) {
                return $item;
            }
        }

        return $alreadyInCart;
    }

    //returns current shoppingcart contents.
    private function getContent()
    {
       return $this->instance->cartItems;
    }
}
```

Now inside the `addCartItem`-method i try to push the new cartitem into the array using `array_push()`but `var_dump()`-ing the session afterwards shows the session does not contain the newly added item. However, if i `var_dump()` the `$content` before and after the `array_push`-method, i can see it's added.

I thought PHP would pass the session by reference but apparantly i'm missing something here.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to return the session by reference, i.e.

```
static function &getSessionData($key = null, $data = null)
```

and use it by getting its reference, like:

```
$myVariable = &SessionController::getSessionData($this->sessionName);
```

Quote from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.references.return.php):

> Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to
>   find to which variable a reference should be bound. Do not use
>   return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will
>   automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when
>   you have a valid technical reason to do so. To return references, use
>   this syntax:

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $value = 42;

    public function &getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue;                // prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the changes are still not saved after altering my code the way you said i should. Is there something wrong with passing a specific session-element by reference? (like is it a bad practice or..?)

Comment: @Mathijs can you edit your question and add the way you have tried?

Comment: Your answer was correct. I had to add it to the `getContent()`-method as well. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: although i'm still wondering if this is the right thing to do? Is this concidered to be a good practice or not?

Comment: @Mathijs returning references by themselves are not good or bad practices, they are possibilities. What makes this a good or a bad practice is the context. If you see any possibility that those references would be mishandled by a server-code, then it is a bad practice. If you do not see such a danger, then it is a good practice. If you see no other possibility, then it is a necessary practice. In general, you should not return anything by reference without a good reason. In our case I think you can achieve your goal in a more elegant manner.

Comment: @Mathijs You can move everything which directly changes session values into the SessionController class and wrap methods around them. This will protect you from solving the same thing several times and any necessity can be resolved by the class.

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually persisting(saving) the data into the `Session`.

Try using the `Session` facade by doing something like `Session::put('new.item' , $cartItem)`.

Then you may retrieve the Item in your Controller via: `Session::get('new.item')`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but wouldn't passing the session by reference make sure adding anything to `$instance` like `array_push($instance, $cartItem)` is the same as saying `Session::put('shoppingcart', $cartItem)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works in this case because you're utilizing Laravel's Session manager (it's a wrapper over the `$_SESSION` global), so you must play by their rules as opposed to referencing the session global directly :)

Comment: I just built a simple Shopping Cart very recently (albeit on Lumen), maybe this will help you: https://gist.github.com/MattWohler/1917e0d92b391536b6f2bbaff90923ed

`Basket.php` is a wrapper around the Session. So in my case my Cart is a Session where as yours is a table in a DB. Hope it helps.